# Why calling a generic overridden function produces 2 stack frames in Java

Tags: java, generics

I've noticed that sometimes the call of my overridden function produces two stack frames instead of one. And after some experiments, I noticed that it is somehow connected with generic return type.

There is an example:

```java
public class MyTest {
    interface A<T> {
        T a();
    }

    static class AA implements A<String> {
        @Override
        public String a() {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail");
        }
    }

    static void myFun(A<String> a) {
        a.a();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myFun(new AA());
    }
}
```

And running these test prints:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: fail
    at MyTest$AA.a(MyTest.java:9)
    at MyTest$AA.a(MyTest.java:6)
    at MyTest.myFun(MyTest.java:14)
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:18)
...
```

And if I replace generic return type with the exact return type, e.g.

```java
public class MyTest {
    interface A<T> {
        String a();
    }

    static class AA implements A<String> {
        @Override
        public String a() {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail");
        }
    }

    static void myFun(A<String> a) {
        a.a();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myFun(new AA());
    }
}
```

The resulting exception will look like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: fail
    at MyTest$AA.a(MyTest.java:9)
    at MyTest.myFun(MyTest.java:14)
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:18)
```

What does produce this additional stackframe `at MyTest$AA.a(MyTest.java:6)` (line 6 is `static class AA implements A<String> {`)?
Thanks!

EDT:
Also, adding generic parameter produces this behavior.
E.g.

```java
public class MyTest {
    interface A<T> {
        String a(T t);
    }

    static class AA implements A<String> {
        @Override
        public String a(String s) {
            throw new RuntimeException(s);
        }
    }

    static void myFun(A<String> a) {
        a.a("fail");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myFun(new AA());
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: fail
    at MyTest$AA.a(MyTest.java:9)
    at MyTest$AA.a(MyTest.java:6)
    at MyTest.myFun(MyTest.java:14)
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:18)
```

Tests are run on Java 11.

EDT 2: remove test library

Comment: Yes, there is should be "fail", I've replaced "kek" to more appropriate message, but forgot to change code in question.

Comment: Line 8 is `static class AA implements A<String> {`

Comment: @user15793316, I got it, thank you!

Comment: @matt, It was more comfortable for me to use the test library. I've changed snippets to get rid of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before J2SE 5.0, Java did not have covariant return types. The JVM bytecode rules are that it overrides on exact parameter match including the return type. So the compiler inserts a *synthetic* *bridge* method that you are seeing.

Perhaps surprisingly, the JLS doesn't talk much about bridge methods. It is in the notes on the section [Create Frame, Synchronize, Transfer Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.5)  in the Expressions chapter.